# Logitech Unified Receiver Mouse M510 (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)

Tags: 16.04, xorg, mouse, logitech

The mouse is associated with the receiver, detected and seen by the Solaar applet but the curstor doesn't move. What should I try to fix?

This M510 mouse was/is working with Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows. The machine is the Dell XPS 13 laptop with pre-installed Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. Synaptics touchpad is working fine too.

dmesg

```
[123638.604824] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[123638.751916] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[123638.751922] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[123638.751926] usb 1-1: Product: USB Receiver
[123638.751930] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[123638.759981] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0009: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input2
[123638.886815] input: Logitech M510 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0009/0003:046D:1025.000A/input/input21
[123638.887421] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:1025.000A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M510] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1:1
```

/var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[123639.458] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M510 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[123639.458] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[123639.458] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[123639.497] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech M510 (/dev/input/event7)
[123639.497] (**) Logitech M510: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[123639.497] (**) Logitech M510: Applying InputClass "natural scrolling for mouse wheel"
[123639.497] (II) LoadModule: "mouse"
[123639.497] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module mouse
[123639.497] (II) UnloadModule: "mouse"
[123639.497] (II) Unloading mouse
[123639.497] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)
[123639.497] (EE) No input driver matching `mouse'
```

Besides apt says: E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-input-mouse. It seems to be last available for wily.

Answer (score 3):

The culprit was the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-natural-scrolling.conf
that I have added trying to resolve the inverted scrolling direction problem of the laptop touchpad.
It had the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "natural scrolling for mouse wheel"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "mouse"
        Option "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
        Option "Protocol" "Auto"
        Option "ZAxisMapping" "5 4"
EndSection
```

it seems to have no effect on the scrolling though. 
EDIT: the below file doesn't seem to have any effect on the scrolling but breaks the mouse functionality. I have deleted it but do not have the problem with the wrong scrolling direction anymore.

Comment: Try `Option "NaturalScrolling" "off"` or `Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"`

Comment: thanks! I just don't seem to need this file at all, so just deleted it and the scrolling is still OK.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This same config file was the culprit for my question, too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/913192/my-mouse-is-in-lsusb-and-even-generates-events-on-dev-input-mice-but-x-doesnt